# Exception in Main Window while SizeChanged event used

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `wpf` solution, where I have created `UserControl` for trending. This `UserControl` is used in MainWindow.

The path of trend is painted on method showData() of current `class` ChartControl. But because I want to have actual picture of path related to main window size, I have add `SizeChanged` event where this showData() method is called.

My code for event here:

```
private void OnResize(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.showData();
        }
```

Edit:

```
   private List<ChartData> data = new List<ChartData>();
   public void showData()
            {
                double maxVal = this.maxVal();
                double minVal = this.minVal();
                TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan();
                timeSpan = this.maxTime() - this.minTime();
                double stepSize = Area.ActualWidth / timeSpan.TotalSeconds;

                setLabels();

                Area.Children.Clear();

                for (int i = 1; i < this.data.Count; i++)
                {
                    Line lineHorizont = new Line();
                    lineHorizont.StrokeThickness = 2;
                    lineHorizont.Stroke = Brushes.Red;

                    lineHorizont.X1 = (this.data[i].X - this.minTime()).TotalSeconds * stepSize;
                    lineHorizont.Y1 = Math.Abs(((this.data[i - 1].Y - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal) * Area.ActualHeight) - Area.ActualHeight);

                    lineHorizont.X2 = lineHorizont.X1;
                    lineHorizont.Y2 = Math.Abs(((this.data[i].Y - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal) * Area.ActualHeight) - Area.ActualHeight);

                    Area.Children.Add(lineHorizont);

                    Line lineVertical = new Line();
                    lineVertical.StrokeThickness = 2;
                    lineVertical.Stroke = Brushes.Red;

                    lineVertical.X1 = (this.data[i - 1].X - this.minTime()).TotalSeconds * stepSize;
                    lineVertical.Y1 = Math.Abs(((this.data[i - 1].Y - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal) * Area.ActualHeight) - Area.ActualHeight);

                    lineVertical.X2 = (this.data[i].X - this.minTime()).TotalSeconds * stepSize;
                    lineVertical.Y2 = lineVertical.Y1;

                    Area.Children.Add(lineVertical);
                }

                //Draw cross coordinator
                coordX1.StrokeThickness = 1;
                coordX1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                coordX1.X1 = 0;
                coordX1.Y1 = Mouse.GetPosition(Area).Y;
                coordX1.X2 = Area.ActualWidth;
                coordX1.Y2 = coordX1.Y1;
                Area.Children.Add(coordX1);

                coordX2.StrokeThickness = 1;
                coordX2.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                coordX2.X1 = Mouse.GetPosition(Area).X;
                coordX2.Y1 = 0;
                coordX2.X2 = coordX2.X1;
                coordX2.Y2 = Area.ActualHeight;
                Area.Children.Add(coordX2);
            }

public double maxVal()
        {
            List<double> data = new List<double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.data.Count; i++)
            {
                data.Add(this.data[i].Y);
            }
            return data.Max<double>();
        }
```

edit2:
`xaml` content of Main Window

```
<Grid Margin="0">
        <lib:ChartControl x:Name="Trend" Margin="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid>
```

`xaml` content of ChartControl

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" Cursor="Cross" PreviewMouseMove="OnMouseMove">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF1F1F1" Grid.RowSpan="10"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFD4D4D4"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFD4D4D4" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFD4D4D4" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFD4D4D4" Grid.Row="6"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFD4D4D4" Grid.Row="8"/>
            <Canvas x:Name="Area" Grid.RowSpan="10"/>
        </Grid>
```

After start of program everything is working fine and according expectations, but I am getting Exception in View Designer in Visual studio, which is eliminating any design changes.

[image: exception]

Comment: Thx for downvote, but some hint, why it's bad question would be useful.

Comment: I  guess stacktrace is quite informative. `chart.lib.ChartCOntrol.maxVal()` is using `Linq.Max` but it has no elements

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code of showData.

Comment: Share your xaml content.

Comment: in the onresize event you must test this.IsInDesignMode() if you have no data then return....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<double> data = new List<double>();
 for (int i = 0; i < this.data.Count; i++)
 {
   data.Add(this.data[i].Y);
 }
 return data.Max<double>();
```

Please, please, please don't name your local variables the same as your outer-scope variables.

As for why this is failing, it's obvious:

`this.data` is empty when this is called, as such, when you try to perform `data.Max<double>()` you get an exception.

You're calling `MaxVal()` at the very beginning of `ShowData()` and as far as I can see, there's no real discernible place you're adding any `ChartData` to the data list.

Comment: Ok, I will try to avoid this naming fail, but still, I get exception not after application start, only in View Designer, application is working fine. this.data are added right after application start. I have tried to remove calling maxVal() method, but no difference.

Comment: The stack trace shows it's going onResize->showData->maxVal; so at the time the designer kicks in, maxVal is failing because the data collection is empty.

Comment: Thanks I got it, it helped, but I have similar methods for calculate something with that List, so I have to code it different way.

Answer (score 1):

In the `OnResize` event handler you must test that the current instance is not in design mode.

```
System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)
```

if you have no data then return...then no more design exception !!

```
private void OnResize(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        this.showData();
}
```

Comment: What namespace should be used for this method? I have error while using this.

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)

Comment: Thanks, this is also good solution, but it's just a fix of my bad approach, more correct is probably figure out how to don't call methods if there are no data.

Comment: sure that you have to check if you have no data, but GetIsInDesignMode is very usefull to create fake design data for designer when they work on xaml - so you can combine both